# height of sum of prime ideals

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

Suppose $R$ is a Cohen-Macaulay local ring and $P,Q$ are prime ideals in $R$. Let the height of $P$ and $Q$ be $m$ and $n$ respectively. Then is it true that the height of $P+Q$ is at most $m+n$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Take $R=k[[x,y,z,t,u]]/(xy+zt)$, $\mathfrak{p}=(x,z)$, $\mathfrak{q}=(y,t).$ Then $\operatorname{ht}(\mathfrak{p})=\operatorname{ht}(\mathfrak{q})=1 $ but $\operatorname{ht}(\mathfrak{p}+\mathfrak{q})=3 $.